# Can this postgres paging sql's performance be improved?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, paging

I have a HTTP client that wishes to simply send in an offset in a query string to handle paging eg `http://foo.com/cars?offset=50`.

In response they get a model that has the total item count and an array of data. `{"totalitemcount":100, "data":[{"id":1,"name":"Porsche"},{"id":2, "name":"Ferrari"}]}`

The SQL that I use to do this is below:

```
select count(items.id) over() as totalitemcount, items.* from ( 
      select * from cars 
      order by id
      ) as items 
limit 20 
offset 50
```

I'm not sure how performant this approach is and was wondering with the constraints above whether changes could be made to improve it?

Comment: I'm not sure the inner `ORDER BY` will be taken into account by the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: It is highly recommended to avoid `OFFSET` for paging as it requires the all preceeding records to be scanned and is not at all performant. You should be using your `id` field for filtering/paging instead. See this great post: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to first query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cars 
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 20;
```

Then remember the *last* `id`.

The next page is retrieved with

```
SELECT * FROM cars 
WHERE id > [the id you remembered]
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 20;
```

And so on.

This way you don't get the total count of results, but you gain efficiency.

Do you *really* need the exact total number? If an approximation is enough, try the idea at the end of [this blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/count-made-fast/).

Comment: How do you know when in the client how many pages to link to eg 1,2,3, next, last if there is no total count.  What if id 3, 6,8 are deleted? How do you calculate the next page id?

Comment: Since you don't know the total count with thid method, you cannot tell right away how many pages there will be. However, you don't need to know the next `id`: the condition `id > [last id]` will automatically find the next `id`, and it can use an index on the column to do that efficiently.